# React: How to override input class in Material-UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, bootstrap-5

I am working on a React project, where I have been using Bootstrap for front-end. I have integrated Autocomplete library from Material-UI.

#ref: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

**Problem:** I am trying to integrate `form-control` class inside the input tag. But it's not working.

**Tried:**

```js
<Autocomplete
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={this.props.customers}
    onChange={(_, value) => {
    console.log(value);
    }}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
    <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
        <input
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Search by client name"
        type="text"
        {...params.inputProps}
        />
    </div>
    )}
/>
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

**Expectation**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up having a solution with CSS. I copied the css code of `.form-control` class and put in combo-box-demo ID.

```css
input#combo-box-demo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```